# To-do-notes in a separated TeX file

Tags: todonotes

Is it possible to compile a file with the `extract` package that just includes the `\listoftodos` (`todonotes` package) of another file?

Comment: Related Question: [To-do-notes in separate TeX File, but without \listoftodo in main doc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112688/to-do-notes-in-separate-tex-file-but-without-listoftodo-in-main-doc).

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to use the `extract` package for this.  Provided you have compiled your main file `main.tex` with the todo notes in it, there will be an auxilliary file `main.tdo` containing the list of todo's.  Now all you need in a second document is to include that file `main.tdo`.  Here is a working set-up:

First: `main.tex`

[image: Main file]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

Text.\todo{Something needs doing here.}

\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

Second: `todolist.tex`

[image: Todo file]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\input{main.tdo}

\end{document}
```