# To-do-notes in separate TeX File, but without \listoftodo in main doc

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, auxiliary-files, todonotes

I am using [the `todonotes` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes) and have three requirements, the first two which the MWE already does:

1. Obtain a list of `todo` notes in a separate auxiliary file. This can easily be obtained via the `\listoftodos` as per the similarly named question referenced below.
2. Have the `\todo` appear in the document -- also works.
3. What does *not* yet work: I do *not* want the list of `todo` to appear in the header of this document.

The MWE below generates (after two runs):

[image]

The correct result should be only the two `todo` notes in yellow and pink,
and the `.tdo` file needs to be newer than the .tex file

### Notes:

- Did not automate the testing of the case where the MWE is run as is, and then upon second run the `\listoftodos` is commented out -- This will seem to produce the desired result, as an older  `.tdo` file exists.  However, I would prefer a solution that yields the correct result upon first compile.

### Background:

- I have numerous small files and having a list of todo in each file is not that helpful. My plan is to post process all the individual `todo` auxillary files to obtain a single document that has all the `todo` notes along with links to the files that created them.

### References:

- [To-do-notes in a separated TeX file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95217/to-do-notes-in-a-separated-tex-file)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}%

\begin{document}
\listoftodos% Want the temporary file generated

\bigskip


\todo[inline,color=yellow,caption={Fix me}]{There should be no text above this line (as if listoftodos was commented).}


\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{%
    %  Yeah, we have the temporary file
    \todo[inline,color=red!20]{Temporary .todo file exist. 
      But need to ensure that it was not left over from a previous run...}
}{%
    \todo[inline,color=red]{Failed: No .todo file...}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want `\@starttoc` without the file input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}%

\makeatletter
\newwrite\tf@tdo
\immediate\openout\tf@tdo\jobname.tdo\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\bigskip


\todo[inline,color=yellow,caption={Fix me}]{There should be no text above this line (as if listoftodos was commented).}


\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{%
    %  Yeah, we have the temporary file
    \todo[inline,color=red!20]{Temporary .todo file exist. 
      But need to ensure that it was not left over from a previous run...}
}{%
    \todo[inline,color=red]{Failed: No .todo file...}
}
\end{document}
```