# How to intelligently handle notes to self?

Tags: notes

I'm new to LaTeX, and I thought it would be a good idea to keep my notebook of experiments in it.

It is often my habit, when writing about the experiments I have conducted, to write "notes to self". These are lessons I learned from that experiment that will apply to similar future experiments.

However, when I am about to attempt a new experiment, I would much rather not scan the whole notebook for notes pertaining to it. Is there any way to make LaTeX collect all such notes to self under a separate heading, and include a reference for each so I can go back and see which experiment that note was made on?

Comment: Check out [the `todonotes` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes).  That's what I use and works great.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you, this is almost what I am looking for. However, is it possible to have classes of todos, such that each class is collected in a different list (for each class of experiments)? Or must all todos be collected in only one list?

Comment: I don't know how to get separate lists but I use different colors for different types of `todo`. An example is at [To-do-notes in separate TeX File, but without \listoftodo in main doc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112688/to-do-notes-in-separate-tex-file-but-without-listoftodo-in-main-doc).

Comment: I've used a redefinitions of the todo-call in one of my manuscripts to have different todos for different authors, which worked quite nice, also for visual separation in the `\listoftodos`. Take a look at 1.8.4 in the manual.

Comment: `fixme` supports multi-author notes of various kinds and you could use the prefixes to denote different sorts of notes or notes for different classes of experiments as easily as different authors. You can suppress or show the notes at will and there's a command to print a complete list of fixmes with page references. You can also choose various indications in the text - everything from a 'clue' in the margin to the full text of the note inline in a different font. I don't know how this compares with `todonotes` as I've not used the latter.

Comment: See my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160, in which I extended my answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text/142258#142258 to handle multiple recipients/topics, etc.